# How are we defining New Users?

Tags: support, new-users, users-page

Under Users tab, we can see New Users section. My question is, What all factors are we considering to put a user under "New User" category ? For example, are we considering max number of days visited one of the factor, let's say any user who has spent max 60 days is a new user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we hover on [New users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers) tab, it reads, users who joined in the last 45 days. Users who joined in last 45 days are shown in the list.

While calculating days, system adds joining day and today also. So, a user who joined yesterday will shown as "101 in 2 days". But actually, they were member only for a day.  Similarly, if a user joined 45 days ago, it shows 46 days. A user who joined on 21st April will be shown as "101 in 46 days" but they were member only for 45 days. I calculated the days between joining date and today (June 5 as of writing this answer) using a website.

[image]

So, it is based on user's joining date.

Comment: Check this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=97&tab=newusers , Yoshika joined 46 days back. 45 days is not correct it seems.

Comment: It is the difference because of timezones. I calculated the time manually, it shows 45 days. @TheLittleNaruto